# How do I make the value of an array variable constant in C?

Tags: arrays, c, const-correctness

I have the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const * const argv[], char const * const * envp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; *envp != NULL; i++, envp++) { 
        printf("envp[%d]: %s\n", i, *envp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles as expected with no warnings.

If I make the envp pointer const, by changing its declaration to the following.

```
char const * const * const envp
```

Then compilation fails as follows.

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:45: error: increment of read-only parameter ‘envp’
    9 |     for (int i = 0; *envp != NULL; i++, envp++) {
      |
```

This makes sense to me: In this program we can declare that the (first and only first?) character value of each environment string is a constant, we can declare that each pointer to each environment string is constant, but we cannot declare that the char** envp is a constant.

Now, my question is, how could I declare the array variable `argv` a constant in a similar way, so that `argv` cannot be reassigned?

That is, I want to declare `argv` in a such a way that the following would produce a similar compilation error to the `"read-only parameter ‘envp’"` error above. I want the following to fail to compile. As is, the following compiles.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const * const argv[], char const * const * envp) {
    char const * const argvbad[1] = { NULL };
    argv = argvbad; // I want this to be impossible

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; *envp != NULL; i++, envp++) { 
        printf("envp[%d]: %s\n", i, *envp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a question about array variables in general. I want to learn how to declare array variables as constant, so that the array that they refer to cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Did you tried `char const * const * const argv` ?

Comment: sure, we know that `char const * const * const argv` would work in a similar fashion to the `envp` example. my question here is about array declarations in general. this is a minimal working example.

Comment: In an argument list, an array declaration is just syntactic sugar for a pointer declaration. But array declaration syntax doesn't provide a way to specify that the array name is `const` (because ordinarily arrays are non-modifiable). You need to use the explicit pointer syntax to do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of helper functions and libraries that really enjoy re-arranging and re-assigning argv.  I would rather it be constant (and I tried).   And envp can't be constant, it is necessary to update environment variables at times.   I was just recently using a library that has really stupid expectations, and had to save and restore an environment variable.

Comment: @TomKarzes the example with `envp` above is just to demonstrate the type of compiler error when a `* const varname` is present. In this program that declaration would be invalid of course. What I'm asking about is how to make such a declaration for a plain array (in general). Imagine this array declaration is in the body of some unrelated function, the `argv` (array) and `envp` (pointer) example here is just an example.

Comment: @BradLanam: Those functions and libraries reassign it with your cooperation. If you don't give them a pointer to it (and they're not doing terrible undefined behavior sorts of things), they can't modify it. Declaring it `const` for yourself won't prevent them from modifying it, it just means the compiler will complain/require a cast when you pass your `const` stuff to a function that demands a non-`const` input. If you don't want them to screw with it, make a copy and pass that instead.

Comment: @Barmar: Re “But array declaration syntax doesn't provide a way to specify that the array name is `const` (because ordinarily arrays are non-modifiable)”: Yes, it does, per the specification of array declarators, in C 2018 6.7.6.2.

Comment: @ioyq2d8s Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a parameter declaration, an array can be declared with qualifiers such as `const` inside the brackets, `[` and `]`:

```
void foo(const char * const argv[const]) { … }
```

When the declaration is automatically adjusted to make the declared identifier be a pointer, the qualifiers will be applied to it. The above is equivalent to `void foo(const char * const * const argv)`.

Note that `int main(int argc, char const * const argv[], char const * const * envp)` is not generally appropriate for `main` because the C standard specifies the forms that the declaration of `main` should take, in C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1. Its specification is flexible in that it allows implementations to accept additional forms, but I am not aware of any implementation documenting that `main` may have that form, with the additional qualifiers.

An additional complication is that qualifiers on parameters, directly, are irrelevant for function compatibility. For example, these are compatible declarations:

```
void foo(int *p);
void foo(int * const p);
```

This is because C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 says:

> … (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

However, these would not be compatible:

```
void foo(int *p);
void foo(const int *p);
```

since the above passage applies only to qualifiers directly on the parameters. This raises the possibility that `int main(int argc, char *argv[const])` is a satisfactory declaration of `main` per C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1, since it is compatible with `int main(int argc, char *argv)` and hence may satisfy its allowance of “equivalent” declarations.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `envp` into a constant pointer (to constant pointers to constant data), don't modify it.  Use an indexed `for` loop and indexed access to the `envp` array:

```
for (int i = 0; envp[i] != NULL; i++) 
    printf("envp[%d]: %s\n", i, envp[i]);
```

You already used the subscript notation in the format string; use it in the code too.